# CHOICE OF 2 FROM MULTIPULE CHOICES

Tags: excel-formula

Hope this makes sense.

Column S will have a selection of jobs (35 options) Usually I filter this and manually enter either transport or warehouse depending on the job role. Is there a formula I can use that will generate the warehouse or transport?

Thank you

screenshot

[image]

Comment: What are the conditions that would cause that column to be Warehouse vs. Transport. Please explain the structure and logic of the data as well as the expected solution as if the users here have no knowledge of your spreadsheet. You haven't provided enough information to help you answer your question.

Comment: What ever is in column S, there's 35 job roles that then need sorting into 2 categories

Comment: can you break that down in more clear logic? What about column S tells you this is Transport vs. Warehouse? Does every transport contain a Number, does each one say "Driver"? We need more information to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ISNUMBER(SEARCH` to find substrings for the jobs in column `S`.

You can then use a series of `IF` statements to provide an output (Transport or Warehouse in your case) based on the job in column S.

Whilst you have 35 jobs and Excel will allow you to nest up to 64 different IF functions, it's not advisable to do so and it will start to become unreadable.

Here are 2 basic examples that should get you up and running:

The first example is just looking for the word `'DRIVER'` in column S.  If found it puts `'TRANSPORT'` in column4, if not found it puts `'WAREHOUSE'` in column S.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DRIVER",S2)), "TRANSPORT", "WAREHOUSE")
```

[image]

Going further to a nested IF statement, you could use:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DRIVER",S2)), "TRANSPORT", IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TEA",S2)), "WAREHOUSE", "TRANSPORT"))
```

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYzP1.png]

This checks for `'DRIVER'`.  If found it puts `'TRANSPORT'` in the cell, it then searches for `'TEA'` and if that is found it puts `'WAREHOUSE'` in the cell.  If neither are found, it puts `'TRANSPORT'` in the cell.

Hopefully this should get you up and running.

You might want to read about nested IF statements in Excel: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/12/07/nested-if-excel-multiple-conditions/